# Terraform - How can I get the availability zone from the ec2 instance to use in aws_ebs_volume resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using a TF module to deploy EC2 instances I want to cater for multiple instances and multiple volume attachments. My issue is I want to use the same az as the instance for the volume but if I have 1 instance and 5 volumes I am having issues using count.

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  count = var.instance_count > 0 ? var.instance_count : length(var.subnet_ids)

  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  user_data     = var.user_data
  key_name      = var.keypair_name

  subnet_id                   = var.subnet_ids[count.index]
  associate_public_ip_address = var.associate_public_ip_address

  vpc_security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids
  iam_instance_profile   = var.instance_profile_name

  monitoring                           = var.monitoring
  disable_api_termination              = var.disable_api_termination
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = var.instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior

  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = var.root_volume_size
    delete_on_termination = var.root_volume_delete_on_termination
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "this" {
  for_each = toset(var.subnet_ids)

  id = each.key
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "this" {
  count = var.assign_volume ? length(aws_instance.this) * var.volume_count : 0

  availability_zone = data.aws_subnet.this[aws_instance.this[count.index].subnet_id].availability_zone

  encrypted  = var.encryption
  kms_key_id = var.kms_key

  size = element(var.ebs_volume_size, (count.index))
  type = var.ebs_volume_type

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.name}-${count.index + 1}"
    volume_id = var.volume_id[count.index]
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "this" {
  count = var.assign_volume ? length(aws_instance.this) * var.volume_count : 0

  device_name = element(var.device_name, (count.index))
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.this[count.index].id
  instance_id = aws_instance.this[count.index].id
}
```

I need a better method to get the az as this is coming back with an error as I have 1 instance but a count of 5 ebs volumes.

`availability_zone = data.aws_subnet.this[aws_instance.this[count.index].subnet_id].availability_zone`

ERROR

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 104, in resource "aws_ebs_volume" "this":
│  104:   availability_zone = data.aws_subnet.this[aws_instance.this[count.index].subnet_id].availability_zone
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_instance.this is tuple with 1 element
│     │ count.index is 2
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the terraform code for the EC2 instance creation?

Comment: added aws_instance code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code definitely is not using the subnet resource ID as a key in the data objects, and so the error message is expected. You would need to couple the subnet data to the EBS volumes. This could be awkward and cumbersome (especially given the different enumerables for iteration), and so it would be easier to use the `aws_instance` as a source of truth for the AZ instead as it is already coupled to the EBS. Additionally, we would need to match the element of the EBS volume resource to the instance with some arithmetic:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "this" {
  count = var.assign_volume ? length(aws_instance.this) * var.volume_count : 0
  ...
  availability_zone = aws_instance.this[floor(count.index / var.volume_count)].availability_zone
  ...
}
```

Note also your `aws_volume_attachment` will have similar element indexing issues and would need to be similarly updated for the `instance_id` value.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the comment, I don't believe the `floor(count.index / var.volume_count)` will work as its not looping over the instances to get the same az  to use for the volume.

Comment: @Shaka101 Please read the answer again for understanding and implement for yourself as it does function as desired.

Comment: Just tested this and its working!! thank you Matt. I have also used your suggestion to use the aws_instance as source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to access the instance on this line:

```
  availability_zone = data.aws_subnet.this[aws_instance.this[count.index].subnet_id].availability_zone
```

You are using `aws_instance.this[count.index]` - but `count.index` iterates over the number of volumes, not instances. This will always give you an out of bound error, as the value used to access the instances list will reach / exceed the length of the instances list.

To use the right index, you need to use `floor(count.index / var.volume_count)`:

```
  availability_zone = data.aws_subnet.this[aws_instance.this[floor(count.index / var.volume_count)].subnet_id].availability_zone
```

---

#### Illustrative Example

Consider:

```
var.instance_count      => 3
var.volume_count        => 2
```

Therefore:

```
length(aws_instance.this)    => 3
length(aws_ebs_volume.this)  => 3 * 2 => 6
```

Iteration values:

```
count.index                           => 0 1 2 3 4 5 [Error when value is 3]
floor(count.index / var.volume_count) => 0 0 0 1 1 1 [No error as value is always
                                                      less than var.instance_count]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, the only issue I am seeing with this is if we have 4 instances across 2 availability zones, and we want the volumes of each instance to be in the same az, this would not work as it would pick up the first instance [0] 3 times and then the second instance [1]. This is from my understanding of your example. Thank you.